# WebView SaveInstanceState Not Preventing HTML Controls From Resetting to Original Values

Tags: android, asp.net, webview, xamarin.android

I have a TabbedActivity with 3 tabs.  Weekly, Transfer and Calls.  The Transfer Activity contains a WebView that I want to maintain each time the device reorients.  I found a ton of examples that led me to the below.  With that, the WebView seems to restore to the Saved Instance and the ProgressDialog that shows during OnProgressChange does not show back up after reorienting. However, the site the WebView displays has checkboxes in it.  And if they are checked in Landscape and then turned Portrait (or vice versa) the checkboxes all return to their original unchecked state. The same for my DropDownLists.

```
[Activity]
public class Transfer : Activity
{
    private WebView web;
    private static ProgressDialog progress;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Transfer);                    

        web = (WebView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.web);

        progress = new ProgressDialog(this);

        if (bundle == null)
        {               
            web.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            web.SetWebChromeClient(new CustomWebChromeClient(this));
            web.SetWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient(this));
            web.ClearCache(true);
            web.LoadUrl("http://www.mysite.com");
        }
        else
        {
            web.RestoreState(bundle);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        web.SaveState(outState);
    }

    private class CustomWebChromeClient : WebChromeClient
    {
        private readonly Activity _context;

        public CustomWebChromeClient(Activity context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public override void OnProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress)
        {
            progress.SetTitle(newProgress + "%");

            if (!progress.IsShowing)
                {
                  progress.SetMessage("Please Wait...");
                  progress.Show();
                }
        }
    }

    private class CustomWebViewClient : WebViewClient
    {
        private readonly Activity _context;

        public CustomWebViewClient(Activity context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url)
        {
            if (progress.IsShowing)
                progress.Hide();
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is true, the only way I have found to fix this is putting the following in your manifest file:

`android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"`

I have to warn you: doing this will make your activity not recreate itself on orientation change. this means your portrait layout will not be loaded, so your layout might get messed up. I "fixed" this issue by just reloading all values i had to put in my webview. Android turned out to be able to handle these changes quite quickly.

I hope this helps, Good luck!

Wottah

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly.  What do you mean by "reloading all values I had to put in my webview"?

Comment: well when you edit stuff on your page, usually only the javascript values change, not the URL. but when the orientation changes these values are reset as the URL is reloaded.

Comment: Thanks.  Guess I didn't ask what I meant to.  Exactly how are you saving and reassigning all the values to your webpage?  ViewState, cookies, Preference Manager, Cache?

Comment: I am not. I just know what i want to have changed in the image (I have to edit the properties of a SVG-document). i do not know whether it  is possible to save the things you mentioned.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm just really not following.  I'm 100% self taught so my terminology is not always great.  When you say "reloading all values i had to put in my webview", I really don't know what you're referring to.  Do you have any examples?

Comment: i insert all values using javascript methods like this one

 `function updateTextField(id,val)
 {
  document.getElementById(id).firstChild.textContent=val;  
 }`